# Xamarin iOS : Center UILabel inside UICollectionView Header created programmatically

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

The solution for centering any subview within a parent is usually simple, however, it doesn't seem to work in my case.

I'm working with a UICollectionView and have added a Header class programmatically. I have this constructor, where I also try to center the label within the screen:

```
 [Export("initWithFrame:")]
    public Header(System.Drawing.RectangleF frame) : base(frame)
    {
        label = new UILabel
        {
            Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(frame.Size.Width / 2, 50, 200, 50),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
            TextColor = UIColor.White,
            Font = UIFont.FromName("HelveticaNeueLTStd-ThCn", 35f),
            Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("Y")
        };

                AddSubview(label);
    }
```

And I initialize the class inside the `UICollectionViewSource` 's constructor like this:

```
  public MyCollectionViewDataSource(MainController mainController, DateTime currentDate)
    {
        try
        {

            controller = mainController;

        new Header(new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)mainController.View.Frame.Size.Width, 200));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

        }

    }
```

What exactly am I missing because this usually works in other instances but seems to fail here?

This is what it looks like :
[image: Still positioned at the edge of my screen]

Comment: If you only show a label, you could consider making it full width and set text alignment to center.

Comment: I actually have two buttons, representing forward and back arrows to the left and right of this label. They are currently commented out because I'm still not able to center the label. So they are incorrectly positioned as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an explanation here  [iOS Layout Gotchas](http://blog.adamkemp.com/2014/11/ios-layout-gotchas-and-view-controller.html)  by Adam Kemp which helped me resolve this issue.

**The first solution**

One very common mistake I made was adding the layout definition code in the constructor, instead of doing it in the rightful place :  the **LayoutSubviews** override in this case.

Giving the label the frame size in the constructor assumes a static size set at the time of construction, which may later change depending on the screen size.

**The second solution**

He explains that :

> *Frame* sets the position of a view within its parent while *Bounds* is in the coordinate system of the view itself (not its parent).

So, to center the UILabel, I used bounds and center together and this worked for me.

```
  [Export("initWithFrame:")]
    public Header(CGRect bounds) : base(bounds)
    {
        label = new UILabel
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
            TextColor = UIColor.White,
            Font = UIFont.FromName("HelveticaNeueLTStd-ThCn", 35f),
            Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("Y"),
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center

        };

        rectangle = bounds;

        AddSubview(label);

    }




   public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        label.Bounds = new CGRect (rectangle.Size.Width / 2, 50, 200, 50);
        label.Center = new PointF((float)rectangle.Size.Width/2,50);

    }
```